# displaying a php contact form conditional upon cookie

Tags: cookies

I have php contact form with a submit button, what i would like to do is display this form conditional upon a cookie.

For example, if websitecookie =1, then display the contact form, or else display a message such as "form has already been completed." or even display a page with just one image in the center such as image.png and nothing else.

The solution is something along the lines of:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['websitecookie'])
{
    die('You may only submit this form once per session!');
}
```

But im getting stuck as to how i can add the contact form and image.png values within the condition. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To me, it seems you're trying to avoid spam.

If that's the case, you should know that spam is mostly generated by bots looking for forms open to the public, without any form of validation. Cookies won't stop them!

To prevent this, you could insert a captcha.
http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captcha

In all other cases, the best options seems to require visitors to login so you can track their last 'submit' through a timestamp in the database.

Comment: not trying to evade spam, i would just like to insert a image saying "section complete" conditional upon a page the user visited previously. This previous page would have been the one to set the cookie.